# Is there a way to determine whether a list of integers can be a prefix function?

Tags: algorithms, strings, substrings

Say you had

(0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

or

(0,1,0,1,0,1,2,3,0,1,0,0,1)

Could you use, for example, the KMP algorithm to deduce the validity of the above lists as prefix functions? I know there is a way to find whether a substring exists in a string using KMP, but is there a way to do it the other way around, starting at the apparent prefix function and ascertaining that it is indeed a possible prefix function, without knowing the string/substring itself at the start?

Comment: What is a prefix function?

Comment: What have you tried? You can just emulate KMP (`j = p[j-1]` while current prefix function is greater than what we want to achieve in current position) and check that there are no contradictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Denote by $p$ the input prefix function. Refer to the characters of a word having $p$ as prefix function by their indexes $V=\{0,1,2,...,\operatorname{length}(p)-1\}$. We will keep a set of pairs $D$ of elements of $V$ to represent the characters that must be different. Finally, $V$ will be partitioned into equivalence classes according to the characters of the word that must be equal. I assume that to answer this question it is also given which is the alphabet $\Sigma$ of allowed letters to use. A possible variant of the question would give also a dictionary $L$ of allowed words.

**Algorithm**

- A non-zero as first entry tells you right away that the sequence is not a prefix function.
- Each positive value in $p$ tells you equality between certain pairs of characters of the potential word having that (presumptive) prefix function. Keep track of the equivalence classes that these equalities define, maybe with a [disjoint set union data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).
- If you ever find an increase by more than $1$ ($p[k+1]>p[k]+1$) you can return immediately that it isn't a prefix function.
- Whenever, the sequence doesn't increase it will also tell you one pair of characters that must be different. Collect these pairs in $D$.
- Run by the pairs $D$ of vertices that must be different. If any belong to the same class return `false`.
- Finally, consider the graph $G$ with vertices given by the equivalence classes obtained above and where the edges are the elements of $D$. If only the alphabet $\Sigma$ is given, then we compute if the vertices of $G$ can be colored with the elements of $\Sigma$ such that [adjacent vertices don't get the same color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Algorithms). In the variant in which the dictionary $L$ is given, then we check if any word in $L$ has the length of $p$ and its characters that are in positions being in the same equivalence classes are equal, and the characters forming a pair in $D$ are different. If these conditions are satisfied we output `true`. Otherwise we output `false`.

Let's do your examples.

**Example 1:** Given $p=(0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)$, then $V=\{0,1,2,...,12\}$. That $p[0]=0$ tells us that we don't return `false` right from the beginning. That $p[1]=0$ tells us that characters $0$ and $1$ must be different. So, we insert $\{(0,1)\}$ in $D$. That $p[2]=0$ makes us insert $(0,2)$ in $D$. The rest of the entries of $p$ increase by $1$. So, we never return with a `false` caused by an increase larger than $1$. Moreover, there are no new insertions in $D$, but we do get the equivalence classes $\{0,3,6,9,12\},\{1,4,7,10\},\{2,5,8,11\}$. Since the two pairs in $D$, $(0,1)$ and $(0,2)$ don't consist of elements belonging the same equivalence class then we output `true`. Well, conditional of the variants of the problem in which the alphabet is small and the variant in which the dictionary of all words are given.

For example, the word $1231231231231$ has $p$ as prefix function. Well, if the alphabet has less than $2$ letters then we could give the example $1221221221221$. If the alphabet has only $1$ letter, we would need to output `false`.

**Example 2:** Given $p=(0,1,0,1,0,1,2,3,0,1,0,0,1)$, then $V=\{0,1,2,...,12\}$. That $p[0]=0$ makes us not return `false` from the beginning. That $p[1]=1$ tells use that $0$ and $1$ are in the same equivalence class. That $p[2]=0$ makes us insert $(0,2)$ in $D$. That $p[3]=1$ tells us that $0,1,3$ are in the same equivalence class. That $p[4]=0$ makes us insert $(0,4)$ in $D$. that $[5]=1$, tells us that $\{0,1,3,5\}$ are in a equivalence class. I guess you can continue. At the end the only equivalence class with more than $1$ element is $\{0,1,3,5,6,9,12\}$. The rest of the characters are on their own equivalence classes. In $D$ we have the pairs $(0,2),(0,4),(0,7),(0,8),(0,10),(0,11)$. None of these consist of characters from the same equivalence class. So, we return `true`.

For example, the word $0010200130450$ has $p$ as prefix function.

Let me add an example that returns `false` to have an example of that case.

**Example 3:** Given $p=(0,0,1,2,3,4,2,0)$, then $V=\{0,1,2,...,6\}$. Since $p[0]=0$ we don't return `false` from the beginning. That $p[1]=0$ makes us insert $(0,1)$ in $D$. That $p[2]=1$ tells us that $0,2$ are in the same equivalence class. That $p[3]=2$, tell us that $1,3$ are in the same equivalence class and that $0,2$, which we already knew are also equivalent. That $p[4]=3$ tells that $0,4$ are equivalent, $1,3$, which we knew, and $2,4$, which by now we knew too. That $p[5]=4$ tells that $1,3,5$ are equivalent. Now, that $p[6]=2$ tells us that $6$ and $1$ are equivalent. That's okay so far. But it also tells us that $0$ and $5$ are equivalent. Now, the problem with that is that that makes $1$ (which is equivalent to $5$) in the same equivalence class as $0$, but $(0,1)$ is a pair in $D$. So, we will have to return `false`.